# Strange margin at top of page?

Tags: css

at the top of tis page:

http://randompeoplepics.com there is a margin but the body is covering whole page with no margin set.

Fire bugged it all and don't see why it's create a margin between top and the top menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CleanNav div has a 10px margin

Comment: yes a bottom margin but no top margin. This margin I see is above cleanNavi but the body has no margin top either...

Comment: if the margin you are seeing appears ABOVE the "clear nav" div - then I can't reproduce the error. ClearNav had the only offensive css initially obvious to me

Comment: yup I'm baffled. maybe it's a browser bug.

Comment: @MarkR I've firefox 10.0.1 on Debian Wheezy and the page looks ok - no margin on top of clearNav div. Have you cleared you cache? iceweasel 10.0.2 is behaving right too.

Answer (score 1):

`.CleanNavi` class has a `margin-bottom` set to `10px` (file style.css around line 520). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no above cleanNavi there is a margin between it and top of page.

Comment: I don't see one. In which browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are still experiencing problems, try using a proper CSS reset instead of

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }`

Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

`.CleanNavi` has margin-bottom: 10px

then is height set to (52+10) px